# No default reminder for certain calendars or messages in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook to maintain my calendar, but also, in a second calendar, to maintain what I *have* done (the comparison can be quite useful).

The items in this second calendar obviously shouldn't have a reminder.
Certain types of items (non-appointments) in my regular calendar shouldn't have a reminder, either.

Having to switch off the reminder for each message of these types is very annoying.
Of course, I can set the default reminder to None for everything, but then it will be annoying to miss appointments because I forgot to set their reminders.

So I'd like to have different reminder defaults for different types of calendar entry.

How do I achieve this in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1):

I found a lot of similar requests, and a MS MVP for Outlook indicated you need a third party app for this.  The recommendation was:

[Reminder Manager](http://www.slovaktech.com/remindermanager.htm)

It's NOT free (price $30.00) but it can do a lot and is forward compatible with Outlook 2010 (32bit).

Comment: I know it can be done with scripting but I don't really want to go there.

Comment: I don't need a Reminder Manager.  I just want this particular feature.

Comment: It's not supported without either a 3rd party app or a script.

Comment: I've written a script, but it doesn't work.